# what does it mean a certain update is held back

Tags: package-management, updates

what does it mean a certain update is held back like in the picture I've attached?[image]

the update in question is ubuntu advantage tools that is show held or kept back.

Comment: Check you haven't put any *holds* on packages.. Also try `full-upgrade` as there are conditions where `upgrade` will not upgrade packages, but you haven't provided release details.

Comment: Maybe it means that you need to update your package information first: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`